# Spring MVC request param invalid parameter name

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, request

I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resource/{resourceId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody
ResourceDto getChannelById(@PathVariable Long resourceId, QueryParameters queryParameters) {
    ...
}
```

Which I can call this way:

> GET localhost:8080/someName/resources/1?attr1=1

And attr1 is correctly binded in the QueryParameters object.

I would like to recognize when the call is made with an unknown attribute(attribute not present in the QueryParameters class):

> GET localhost:8080/someName/resources/1?attr1=1&attrUnknown=2

And throw an error. Is possible to recognize an attribute that is not present in the object?

Edit:
Relevant part of the QueryParameters

> private List expand = new ArrayList<>();
>   getters and setters...

Comment: `QueryParameters` belongs to which library. I cannot find it in spring . which verion of spring are you using

Comment: QueryParameters is a pojo I created to store the query parameters

Comment: can you post your `QueryParameters` Pojo